# Problem in installing plugin in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Facing problem in installing a plugin in `WordPress`. It says that:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in C:\xampp\htdocs\simplyauto\wp-admin\includes\class-bulk-upgrader-skin.php on line 160

**This is the code line which is on line no 160:**

```
public function reset() {
    $this->in_loop = false;
    $this->error = false;
}

/**
 */
public function flush_output() {
    wp_ob_end_flush_all();
    flush();
}
```

Please anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Which version of PHP/Wordpress is the plugin for and what versions do you have.

Comment: PHP 7.3.0 AND Wordpress 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading wordpress version. You shouldn't be editing this file as it belongs to core wordpress.

Comment: I have the upgraded version of WordPress. Which file you are talking about in core wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You can try to upgrade wordpress version , or reinstall wordpress core wp-amin folder

Comment: I have the latest version of WordPress and PHP.

Comment: which php and wordpress version are you using ??

Comment: I am sorry which plugin are you installing ??